How to use property() to set a function as property of object but not class?
I'm attempting to use the @property decorator on a specific instance of a class in Python and not on the class itself, but I'm encountering issues. Here is what I typically do:
class MyNet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 1  # Example value

    @property
    def quantized_weight(self):
        return quantize(self.weight)

However, when I try to apply a property to just one instance of the MyNet class, it doesn't behave as expected:
class MyNet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 1  # Example value

net = MyNet()

def quantized_weight(self):
    return quantize(self.weight)

net.quantized_weight = property(quantized_weight)

After executing the above code, when I attempt to access net.quantized_weight, instead of returning the result of the quantize function, it gives me <property at 0x7fdcf422bd30>.
Can someone explain why this occurs and how I can correct it so that the property works on an instance level as intended?
I read the documents on Python property: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property
It shows that property should be used in Class.
I find this: Python property returning property object
So, how can i apply a function as property on an instance? I don't want to break the other instance.

What's wrong with defining the property at the class level?

self outside class is just a regular parameter name, it won't have any of the class attributes.

Properties don't work on individual instances.  It is the act of retrieving a value from the defining class that triggers the "descriptor protocol", which is how properties work.

self is always a regular parameter name. If you have some class Foo: x = 42, then define def bar(self): return self.x outside the class but add it to the lass namespace, e.g. Foo.bar = bar, then Foo().bar() will work

@Olivier I don't want all instances of this class to have this attribute, and since this class definition is library code, I don't want the library code to be modified

One possible approach is to store the quantize function as an instance attribute so it can be updated on a per-instance basis:
class MyNet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 1  # Example value
        self.quantize = lambda value: value

    @property
    def quantized_weight(self):
        return self.quantize(self.weight)

net = MyNet()
print(net.quantized_weight) # outputs 1
net.quantize = lambda value: value * 2
print(net.quantized_weight) # outputs 2


Thank you very much！But  MyNet is actually the code in the library. In fact, I want to modify class Linear in the Pytorch library, but I don’t want to directly modify the library code (although modifying the library code can achieve my purpose). It still seems impossible, thank you very much

It's unusual to have to add attributes to an object outside of a class. You can easily do the kind of thing you want using a subclass:
class MyOwnNet(MyNet):

    @property
    def quantized_weight(self):
        return quantize(self.weight)

The new class will inherit the old constructor, so whenever you need one of the modified objects, use MyOwnNet.
